# How to Restart this Function without running twice if same id selected

Tags: javascript, timer

im trying to add to a table the time an option inside a select is chosen.
ive made a clock to each id but when its selected twice the function run all over again.

ive tryed numerus times to do it diffrently , maybe u have a better idea.

here im calling the element value and assign it to my list.
then im using on change to return obj which is defined below.

```
function userFinish() {
while (counter < ids.length) {
    var row = document.getElementById(ids[counter]);
    var td = document.createElement("TD");
    row.appendChild(td);
    var select = document.createElement("SELECT");
    select.setAttribute("id", counter);
    td.appendChild(select);

    for (var j = 0; j < gurds.length; j++) {
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option.innerText = gurds[j];
        select.appendChild(option);

    }
    counter++;
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var here = document.getElementById(i);
    here.onchange = returnObj;
 }
}
```

as i mentiond here returnobj adds the id to the next funtion so i can chose where to add the new data

```
function returnObj() {
addClock(this.id);
}
```

and here is the improvised Clock.

```
function addClock(selectId) {

if (selectId == 0) {
    var temp = document.getElementById("lobyClock");
    var countSeconds = 0;
    var countMinutes = 0;
    myVar = setInterval(function () {
        if (countMinutes == 60) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        if (countSeconds % 60 == 0 && countSeconds > 1) {
            countSeconds = 0;
            countMinutes++;
        }
        countSeconds++;
        temp.innerText = countSeconds + " : " + countMinutes;
    }, 1000);

}

    else {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }

if (selectId == 1) {
    var temp = document.getElementById("tThreeClock");
    var countSeconds = 0;
    var countMinutes = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (countMinutes == 60) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        if (countSeconds % 60 == 0 && countSeconds > 1) {
            countSeconds = 0;
            countMinutes++;
        }
        countSeconds++;
        temp.innerText = countSeconds + " : " + countMinutes;
    }, 1000);




}
if (selectId == 2) {
    var temp = document.getElementById("tFourClock");
    var countSeconds = 0;
    var countMinutes = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (countMinutes == 60) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        if (countSeconds % 60 == 0 && countSeconds > 1) {
            countSeconds = 0;
            countMinutes++;
        }
        countSeconds++;
        temp.innerText = countSeconds + " : " + countMinutes;
    }, 1000);

}
if (selectId == 3) {
    var temp = document.getElementById("tFiveClock");
    var countSeconds = 0;
    var countMinutes = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (countMinutes == 60) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        if (countSeconds % 60 == 0 && countSeconds > 1) {
            countSeconds = 0;
            countMinutes++;
        }
        countSeconds++;
        temp.innerText = countSeconds + " : " + countMinutes;
    }, 1000);


}
if (selectId == 4) {
    var temp = document.getElementById("tSixClock");
    var countSeconds = 0;
    var countMinutes = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (countMinutes == 60) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        if (countSeconds % 60 == 0 && countSeconds > 1) {
            countSeconds = 0;
            countMinutes++;
        }
        countSeconds++;
        temp.innerText = countSeconds + " : " + countMinutes;
    }, 1000);


}
if (selectId == 5) {
    var temp = document.getElementById("tSevenClock");
    var countSeconds = 0;
    var countMinutes = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (countMinutes == 60) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        if (countSeconds % 60 == 0 && countSeconds > 1) {
            countSeconds = 0;
            countMinutes++;
        }
        countSeconds++;
        temp.innerText = countSeconds + " : " + countMinutes;
    }, 1000);


 }
}
```

Comment: can you add an example i cant understand...